# Error on getting the current datetime and store the Last_Logged_In in Database in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I am having a problem about getting the last_logged_in datetime and stored into table User.

When I log in using email and password, I received the success message and the token. But when I check for the last_logged_in column, the data is null. I am writting this function inside the LoginController

```
protected function authenticated(Request $request, $user)
{
   $user->update([
        'last_logged_in' => Carbon::now()->toDateTimeString(),
   ]);
}
```

When the user is authenticated and log in, the datetime should be stored in database but when I check my database, it is null. In my Model User, i have

```
protected $fillable = [
    'emp_id', 'email', 'password','last_logged_in'
];
```

But it still dont run. Can you guys give me some adjustment on how to get this current datetime and stored the last_logged_in information to database. Thank you.

Comment: When does `authenticated` get called?

Comment: You might have a data type issue. But really, you should just use the "ON UPDATE CURRENT TIMESTAMP" feature rather than getting that time from php. Let code to maintain.

Comment: @vivek. It is in LoginController using JWT Authentication

Comment: @Difster so when i logged in i just use that ON UPDATE CURRENT TIMESTAMP inside the migration only?

Comment: In general, you should use that whenever you need to track when something gets updated in the database.

Comment: This is happen when i want to store datetime of the user last login to database and when they input their account and press login, the token is generated with message success but the field last_looged_in is not stored. 

I set the last_logged_in is timestamp column type.

Comment: Because I saw it is weird that when i press login, that field should be updated but it is not.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you will want to set up round model binding to ensure that you have an instance of the User model:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/routing#route-model-binding

Second if this is coming via an ajax request you will want to use use a public function

Third you can shorten your code by using the date helper `now()` which gives a Carbon object for the current time and then I would let your database convert it to the correct date format for the field

So your code would look like below

```
public function authenicated(Request $request, User $user) { 

    $user->update([
        'last_logged_in' => now()
    ]);
}
```

Comment: this one i write the API so can i still use that code inside?

Answer (score 0):

Use this date("Y-m-d h:i:sa") for current date and time

```
 protected function authenticated(Request $request, $user)
    {
       $user->update([
            'last_logged_in' => date("Y-m-d h:i:sa"),
       ]);
    }
```